# How to configurate NHibernate to use MS SQL 2016 (RTM)?

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate

Version of MS SQL Server which is using by my visual studio is the following:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)

I'm new with NHibernate and I was confused by what type of dialect should I use. 
Is it possible to set the following configuration parameters:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">

      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2016Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=Bookstore.mdf</property>

      <mapping resource="NHibernate_1.Book.hbm.xml" assembly="NHibernate_1" />

   </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 10):

The most recent dialect implemented is [MsSql2012Dialect.cs](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2012Dialect.cs).

Check all available on the latest version of NHibernate source code:

#### https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/tree/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect

- ...
- MsSql2000Dialect.cs
- MsSql2005Dialect.cs
- MsSql2005DialectQueryPager.cs
- MsSql2008Dialect.cs
- MsSql2012Dialect.cs
- ...